# Looking for a framework that uses Java ThreadLocal for generic data collection

Tags: java, frameworks, local

PROBLEM:

We have an existing system which performs many calculations and is somewhat complex.  In fact, at times users dont know how certain data is derived.  (We don't know either without extensive  research into the specifics of the code).  We are working on implementing a feature that would allow us to show the user exactly what was done to produce an answer.

GENERAL SOLUTION:

To accomplish this we need to somehow pass a "context" through our system to which we can add some facts during the processing.  These facts, can then be formatted and presented to the user.

SPECIFIC POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS:

There are two ways that I know of to pass the context.  One way, is to augment every function to introduce a "bucket" or a collection that can be added-to when something needs to be returned to the user.  This would require that we make a lot of changes to our functions/api to receive, possibly modify, and pass on this extra variable to other functions.

Another way, is to use a ThreadLocal variable which we can retrieve anywhere in the thread and populate with data.  Furthermore, we want to make this population seamless to the developer, by wrapping it in java @Annotations which can then be processed by aspects to populate this "context".

It is this idea of using ThreadLocal as an invisible hidden "context" that we want to explore.

SPECIFICALLY:

So, the basic idea, we are looking into is to @Annotate methods such that some facts can be added to a ThreadLocal variable based on parameters passed into the function or results retrieved from the function. This way, we can decorate the functions as we come upon them and those function "automatically" find the context and augment it as specified in the definition of the annotation.

QUESTION (finally):
Is there an existing framework that already exists which does something like this or similar?

Thanks

-AP_

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you can make changes to the code. Have you considered just using a logging framework (like slf4j) and writting trace messages to the log at the entry and exit points of the methods you're interested in? Logging is, basically, auditing, which is what I think you're really looking for.

The difficulty you're going to find with the annotation approach is having some way to process them at runtime. You can use spring aspects if the classes you're talking about are spring beans, or you can use compile-time-weaving (CTW) to introduce advice around the annotated methods to audit information concerning the method's params and return values (at a push you could use load-time-weaving, but that approach really is nonsense for most applications). CTW is much more difficult, but necessary if you're creating instances of objects in code (that is, you're auditing the domain model, rather than the static infrastructure), or you're auditing a big-ball of mud.

Finally, after 35 years of hard-earned experience, I can tell you as a fact (although I can't actually prove it), if you're having these sorts of problems than it's always easier and less expensive to throw away the system you have and re-implement it from scratch. A.l.w.a.y.s.

B

Comment: +1 for `you have an re-implement it from scratch`  I am often amazed how much time developers/teams waste in trying to avoid doing this.  BTW You don't always have to throw everything away at once.  If your system is broken into parts, re-write one critical part (or class) and replace that (doing it the right way this time)  This way you can replace an entire system progressively.  BTW I use Java Chronicle for logging/auditing because a) I wrote it, b) it is very fast. I recently wrote 20,000 million short messages in 20 minutes. It supports text and binary.

Comment: The system is not really broken, perhaps "complex" was not the proper terminology.  It's implementing complicated business requirements.  I have seen broken systems and completely understand where you guys are coming from.  

Logging is an interesting idea, but we need to display something to the user when they ask for more details.  I have written aspects before and used CTW so I am comfortable with that.  What I am not sure about is encoding the spec in the annotation that would let me get the right data and stuff it into the ThreadLocal bucket.  I was hoping someone already did this.

Comment: You could always configure the log to write to a database, not a simple file. Then you can query the db dynamically at runtime to display info to the users. Take a look at [this on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072333/slf4j-logging-to-file-vs-db-vs-solr).